# Why are Angular 2 projects so large

Tags: angularjs, angular

We are in the process of re-writing our ng1 project with ng2. Our ng1 project, when built, is about 8mb. We are about a quarter of the way in our re-write to ng2 and we are already at 14mb for our ng2 prod build.

The major difference in the size of the **dist** folder can be attributed to differing sizes of source maps. Both projects include source maps but ng2 source maps are much larger. This makes sense to me as ng2 has more boilerplate, components are separated out, and so on.

Initially this question was placed **on hold** as it was too large to answer. I agree. But that's precisely why I am asking it. I'm trying to make sense of all the things ng2 offers that will make the final ng2 product better than the ng1 version.

With that, what are some of the practical approaches/procedures/tools that we can apply to our ng2 development practices to keep final sizes small and in turn user experience fast?

Comment: Are you including all the source files (including TS files) in the build?

Comment: @AnthonyC i don't believe so, all i see is chunked js files. Whats the best way to check if ts files are in there?

Comment: Depends on your build configuration, if you open those JS files, do you see something like `//# sourceMappingURL=` in the last line?

Comment: Check this link to confirm expected size: https://gist.github.com/Restuta/cda69e50a853aa64912d

Comment: @AnthonyC yep, source mapping url is in there.

Comment: That must be why then. file with minified+ source could get larger than the original file itself.

Comment: @AnthonyC that's probably the reason. hard to tell when everything is mangled together at the moment. We'll have to rethink our webpack config to separate the maps from minified source. Know of any tools that show what the final composition looks like? Pie chart would be nice :)

Comment: There is a graphical tool: [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer)

Answer (score 6):

I was trying out angular 2 the other day and I faced the same issue as you do, my vendor.js was 6M and this was a simple "Hello World" app...

I've found the following post that helped a lot in understanding how we should act on this issue (for now): http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/06/26/tree-shaking-angular2-production-build-rollup-javascript/

He uses several optimizing and compression techniques (precompile,treeshake, minify, bundle and gzip) on his 1.5M app to reduce its size to just 50kb.

Check it out, hope it helps! :)

Comment: good link ravi. I see that he goes from 1.4mb to 128kb just by minification and gziping it. We do that for both ng1 and ng2 already so even though the size difference is huge, for us thats always been there. Rollup and AoT however I'll have to look into and see what we can leverage there

Comment: I faced that same question awhile back, then I read about AoT, tree shaking, gzip, minification, everything else. I found this repo, https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter.    Check it out. I'm using this now in various production builds.