# Why do plain angular projects contain so much files?

Tags: angular

Today, we, me and my co-worker, copied a plain angular project. We discovered, that this project contained way more than 30.000 files. Why are there so much files? Sure, there is safely a bunch of node modules and other 'hidden' stuff. But anyways, this seams a bit too much for being necessary.
Any idea why this is so big?

P.S. this is no duplicate of [Why are Angular 2 projects so large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271430/why-are-angular-2-projects-so-large)

Comment: Because it has a lot of dependencies that have a lot of dependencies, and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you copied the project in it's working state, with all dependencies, that's not unusual. It's the NPM world we live in now.

Our projects all have at least 15k files:

```
Project, files, space usage/disk usage, disk wasted
A: 38k files, 309MB/364MB, 55MB
B: 39k files, 248MB/301MB, 53MB
C: 15k files, 130MB/150MB, 20MB
D: 17k files, 120MB/140MB, 20MB
E: 17k files, 64MB/84MB, 20MB
```

They are all react+redux and node+express projects. I included disk space wasted mainly for curiousity's sake; to emphasize the large number of small files (.js, package.json, .gitignore, etc.) that each take up entire disk blocks.

NPM installs the dependancies for every other dependancy, so you can get duplicates like:

```
a
+-- b <-- depends on c@1.0.x
|   `-- c@1.0.10
`-- d <-- depends on c@~1.0.9
    `-- c@1.0.10
```

(From [4waisenkinder](http://4waisenkinder.de/blog/2014/06/09/flatten-your-dependencies-with-npm-dedupe/))

If your interested, you can try [`dedupe`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe)ing the files. See:

[npm is installing dependencies in a weird recursive way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241258/npm-is-installing-dependencies-in-a-weird-recursive-way#18262626)

So, moral of the story is delete your `node_modules` folder before copying. No really, it's *way* faster.